# Mongo DB aggregation self join with average

Tags: mongodb, join, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I need to make enough complicated trick with aggregation framework.

I am aggregating logs of the operation state change. (pretty common I guess)

After a couple of pipeline steps I get something like:

```
    {
    "operaiton_id" : "56cf29e90c15c45630347320",
    "timestamp" : 1456417257087,
    "old_state" : "OPEN",
    "new_state" : "IN_EXAM"
    },

    { 
    "operaiton_id" : "56cf29e90c15c45630347320",
    "timestamp" : 1456481305971,
    "old_state" : "IN_EXAM",
    "new_state" : "IN_ALERT"
    },

    ...
    { 
    "operaiton_id" : "33ab23f92999c40638553320",
    "timestamp" : 1458147304895,
    "old_state" : "OPEN",
    "new_state" : "IN_EXAM"
    },

    { 
    "operaiton_id" : "33ab23f92999c40638553320",
    "timestamp" : 1458147310251,
    "old_state" : "IN_EXAM",
    "new_state" : "IN_ALERT"
    }
```

What I am looking for here is an average transition time from each state to each state. Having an SQL I make a self join, kind of:

```
SELECT AVG(a.timestamp - b.timestamp)
FROM a JOIN a AS b ON a.old_state=b.new_state
```

Any ideas how could I do it in Mongo Aggregation? Feeling desperate.

Comment: Probably not the best to tell us *"after a couple of steps in the pipeline"*, as you might be doing it correctly or you might be doing it inefficiently and wrong up until that point. You can do this with [`$lookup`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/) in theory, **but** of course that would likely mean the same sort of "tranformation stages" you already have. So another reason why you should have included the source data and existing process.

Comment: The other obvious thing is that aggregation is not necessarily the best approach. If this is the sort of thing you need to do with your data on a regular basis for analysis, then it's likely you should be modelling differently to what you presently are. But again, without that source information we really are not in a position to give you an informative answer. So your question could do with some improvement in these areas.

Comment: These "couple of steps" are:1) 'unwind' from nested list 2) domain specific filtering. So I don't think that these steps can be changed somehow. Also I can tell that DB is like this and there is no way of remodeling it, it is in production in enterprise. I am making a report on user request from web interface and I know I can easily make it server-side but the question is MongoDB capabilities. If there is an obvious 10-20 LOC solution as I do it in SQL? So I can give it a try and check performance.

Comment: You will never describe this suffieciently with words. Include source document samples in your question along witb your current pipeline code. There is an [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/36203838/edit) link on your question specifically so you can add more detail like this. As the person asking the question, this comments section should only be used to notify people that you have made the clarification requests they asked for.